# Mendeley previous view feature for pdfs?

Tags: pdf, mendeley

Is there a previous view feature in Mendeley for viewing pdfs (similar to the one from Adobe Reader using alt + left arrow) to jump between the source and the destination of a link (for example to the bibliography in a pdf)?

It would be helpful because in combination with highlighting this would make it a quite good pdf reader. Adobe also offers highlight, but changes there are permanent to the file in the sense it modifies the file directly. In Mendeley the highlighted text is permanent only within Mendeley, which is advantageous if you want to share the pdf for example.